# How to create a line starting from x,y coordinates to other x,y coordinates?

Tags: angular, pixi.js, gsap

I'm looking for a way that can move a line had two x,y coordinates forward to other  two x,y coordinates. The length of a line is possible to be long or short.
I assume I can make it come true using by TweenMax and PIXI, but I haven't gotten details to get it yet.
If anyone has ever done things like that, could you teach me how to do it?

I am using Angular6 as a framework.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question need more info.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In Pixi.js you can draw a line with the help of Graphics objects like this.

```
//Creating new Line
const line = new PIXI.Graphics(); 
// If line already present then set its position only
line.position = new PIXI.Point(0, 0);

line.moveTo(0, 0);
line.lineTo(8, 0);
line.lineTo(4, 7);
line.lineTo(0, 0);
```

Here line starting and end at same x,y coordinates ie 0,0 will draw a triangle.